# Integer solutions to a hyperbola

Tags: conic-sections, integer-programming

Is there a way to find all integer solutions to a hyperbola equation?  If it helps, I am specifically looking at "square" hyperbolas (i.e. of the form $\frac{x^2}{z} - \frac{y^2}{z}=1$), where z is an integer (although $\sqrt{z}$ is not necessarily rational).  I suspect that there are a finite number of these solutions, but have no idea how I would go about showing that.

I want to be able to find integer solutions $(x,y)$ for a fixed $z$.

Comment: @Thomas Yes.  Sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: The number of solutions has been repeatedly discussed on this site. It is closely connected to the number of divisors of $z$. There are solutions unless $z$ is divisible by $2$ but not by $4$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Interesting.  I must not have come up with the right keywords to search for.  Could you show me where I could find one of those discussions?

Comment: So you want to find the integer solutions of the quardatic form $ \begin{pmatrix} x & y & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -z \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = 0$, where the matrix is the hyperbola matrix in homogeneous coordinates?

Comment: Sorry, I am horrible at searching. Have answered the question myself, probably more than once!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x^{2}-y^{2}=z \implies (x-y)(x+y)=z$$
So to find integer solutions, consider the factors of $z$.

Comment: For fairly large $z$, factoring it becomes a bit of a chore.  I'm willing to believe that's the best we can do, though.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know of a faster way, and I doubt one exists.

Comment: This is [Fermat's factorization method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_factorization_method)

Comment: @preferred_anon coincidentally that led me to research hyperbolas

Comment: if I can solve hyperbolas quickly, I can solve primes by the same method